# asnyc() doesn't exit at the end of code in ssh and mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous

The following js script connect the SSH and mongodb, create a document in the database.

```
(async function run() {
    try {
        //connect to SSH server
        await tunnel(config)
        console.log(`connected ssh`)
    }
    catch (e) { console.log(e) }

    try{
        //connect to mongodb
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/china_macro');
        var db = await mongoose.connection
        console.log(`connected DB`)
    }
    catch(e){console.log(e)}

    await mongooseModel.create({
        year: 2015
        })
    console.log(`finish`)


})().catch(e=>{console.log(e)})
```

1. I must manually stop (ctrl+c) the program in console at the end. The program wouldn't exit on its own. Why is that?
2. Any improvement I can make on the code?

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting from both ssh and mongoose at the end of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you never disconnect from the ssh server, causing the function to run forever. id also personally recommend you disconnect from  your mongodb database, but i don't think it prevents the program from "ending"